# How get FlexGrid control inside a ng-include file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, wijmo5

I'm building a SPA with Angularjs and Wijmo 5.

I've inserted a Wijmo FlexGrid inside a partial file, then I've included it to the parent page using `ng-include`. The parent page is also an partial file: it's inside the `ng-view`.

```
<wj-flex-grid id="myFlexGrid"
              control="myFlexGrid"></wj-flex-grid>
```

The problem is that I can't reach the FlexGrid control. When i try to declare the flex control, it throws a error: `Cannot read property 'selection' of undefined`.

```
var flex = $scope.myFlexGrid;
var myVar = flex.selection;
```

How can I reach the FlexGrid control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-include` creates a child scope so any directive used within it will be on child scope. You should create flex grid like this -

```
<wj-flex-grid id="myFlexGrid" control="file.myFlexGrid" items-source="file.data" loaded-rows="loadedRows()">
</wj-flex-grid>
```

Here is [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShashankTrivediGC/hug787tL/).